# Associate user to a post in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

hi everyone i'm trying to make a blog and i want to associate a user to post .. and to comment , it's a multi-user blog and i don't know how to do it , any help guys ? !

here is the model file :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
#this is for categories 
class Category(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        #this is where a user can create his own gigs 
class Gigposter(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,blank=False)
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
    categories=models.OneToOneField(Category,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default='',null=False)
    published_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.TextField(default='',max_length=None,blank=False)
    mainphoto=models.ImageField(default='')
    photo=models.ImageField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#this is where a user can comment and say what he thinks about others work
class Comment_area(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
    comment=models.TextField(max_length=None,default='')
    commented_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the views file is empty as you can see :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

Comment: So where exactly is your problem? As I metioned in your previous question, dont use OneToOneFields here! It means that one user is associated with ONE comment or post. Use a Foreignkey to the user and you should be fine.

Comment: @errorinpersona thank so much for answering me , so my problem is when i go to the admin panel , it's up to me to chose the user i want , and i want to the user to be selected automatically .. for exemple here your comment is associated with your name

Comment: Ah okay - so have a look at @Ivan K. s answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically associate a user to a post when working on the admin page, you should redefine `save_model` method of your model. This method describes everything what should be done when you save your model. In your case you should add something like

```
class GigposterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = `request.user`
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Gigposter, GigposterAdmin)
```

to your admin.py. You should also exclude the user field from fieldset in GigposterAdmin. See [this for reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

If you need to identify user in your views, you can always use `request.user`. In particular, you can pass it as a part of the `context` for generating a view. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't recommend using a OneToOneField here, as it tells Django the user is tied to exactly one comment/post (when, a user is likely to post more than once).

You could use `models.ForeignKey`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Gigposter(models.Model):
   # Other properties...
   user = models.ForeignKey(
                    'User'
                     on_delete=models.CASCADE
                 )
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, i'll change it now , but even if i change it , the problem is not solved  , i want  the user to be associated automatically to my model

Answer (score 0):

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)